# Celery rate_limit not imposing the limit

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have two rabbitmq nodes each providing queues for 5 nodes who are running Celery.

Each of the 10 worker nodes run Celery with a concurrency of 4.

When I broadcast a rate_limit to each Celery, the rate does not seem to be the imposed one.

The code I use to broadcast the rate_limit:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker="amqp://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (config.rabbit_user, config.rabbit_pass, rabbit_ip, config.rabbit_vhost))

app.control.broadcast('rate_limit', arguments={'task_name': 'tasks.read', 'rate_limit': '100/s'})
```

From my understanding this limit is per worker instance and not global, therefor I'm expecting 100 messages per second for each celery worker of the 10 nodes. Normally they are consuming about 500-600 per second, yet after the broadcast I get about 1.6 per second on every node. I checked the log and it's about 8 messages every 5 seconds.

Raising the limit to 200/s I'm getting anywhere between 2/s and 2.4/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue and a push was made to solve it.
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3166